# Observed and Observable

Tags: self-study, sampling, interpretation, inference, terminology

What is `observed` and what is `observable`? I found this two word frequently in the context of random variable and realization of random variable.

What is the difference between `observed` and `observable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is as simple as the grammatical form implies.

*Observable* is something that can in principle be observed (a variable or a process that is generating outcomes). 
*Observed* is something that has been observed on a particular occasion (a realization of a variable, an outcome of a process).

For example, if Ann and Tom are rolling dice in another room (you do not see them) and they only report to you the sum of the two scores after each roll, there are two *unobservable* variables (the individual scores) and one *observable* variable (the sum); you have a number of *observed* outcomes (the ones Ann and Tom reported to you). If Ann and Tom are rolling dice right in front of you, all of these variables are *observable*, and all the outcomes are *observed*. If you have observed 10 rolls and then closed your eyes and missed one, this last one was *unobserved*.

Comment: Is unobservable and nonobservable same ?

Comment: I guess so. *Unobservable* is the one I encounter much more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

For example rolling a dice result in an observable experiment and each outcome is an observed event.

Please refer to page 2 of Foundations of Probability in line 15-18. here is the link in google books: 
https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=U427dN6QLxwC&pg=PA2&dq=observable+experiment&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R2TnVK_8OpLW7Ab56oDYDA&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=observable%20and%20observed&f=false

Comment: This is rather sparse & hard to interpret. Can you add more description to flesh it out a little?

Comment: Contrary to the usage here, many texts and papers--including the one you use as a reference!--reserve the term "event" for *measurable sets of outcomes.*  Phrases like "observable experiment" appear redundant: what would a "nonobservable experiment" be?